# How does the samba usershare_acl parameter work?

Tags: configuration, samba, documentation

Looks like it is not even documented on the samba website itself, or did I miss it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best hit I got is from: http://devarthur.blogspot.de/2008/05/integrating-ubuntu-hardy-heron-804-with.html

Summarizing:

```
usershare_acl=Group_SID:access_modifier
```

To get the SID of the a group use:

```
wbinfo -n "DOMAIN\group"
```

SID "S-1-1-0" is Everyone

The access modifiers after the group SID are as follows:

```
R - read-only
F - full access
D - deny access
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straight forward...

usershare_acl=-The user you want to give ACL's to-:-ACL Modifier-

Seem's fairly well documented to be put up as a question that you are answering for yourself the same minute you ask it.... :\

Comment: Indeed, the same minute I posted it I had already been looking around for the best answer I could find, wich looks neither official nor directly related as it is part of a guide for another task, belonging to a blog post. Other idea of well documented maybe :)